# Deep learning Gradient at last but output layer is always zero

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been working with udacity self driving challenge#2. What ever changes I make to the deep network like learning rate, activation function, i am getting gradient zero issue while training. I have used both cross entropy loss and mse loss. For cross entropy 100 classes are used with degree difference of 10 i.e radian angle of 0.17. For example from (-8.2 to -8.03) is class 0 and then (-8.03 to -7.86) is class 1 and so on.

Please find attached screen shots. As seen the layer before output (fc4 in the first image) almost becomes zero. So most of the gradient above almost follows the same pattern. Need some suggestion to eliminate this gradient zero error.

[image: Model_View]

[image: Gradient_Zero_fc4_layer]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be vanishing gradient problem, 1.) Have you tried Relu? (I know you said you have tried diff activation fn)  2.) Have you tried reducing # of layers?  3.) Are your features normalized?

There are architectures designed to prevent this as well (ex. [LSTM](https://www.quora.com/How-does-LSTM-help-prevent-the-vanishing-and-exploding-gradient-problem-in-a-recurrent-neural-network)) but I think you should be able to get by with something simple like above.

Comment: I have tried with relu and elu. But that does not seem to work. Also i tried a simple four layer architecture,but that too fail. I have done only mean and std normalization. Since it is a image,i have not tried any other normalization. Let me check that one. I have not know about LSTM used in classification problem. May be that a good start point to explore more. Thanks.

Comment: I would not recommend going to the architecture route unless there's something really unique about your problem. (It sounds like it's just a standard image classification which has been tried and proven.)  The only other comment I have is that all the hyperparameters and options work together, so you might need to try ReLu simultaneously with a lower # of layers, etc.  Hope you will be able to resolve your problem.

Comment: as point out will try some more combination of hyperparameters